# create channel images gallery from S3

Tags: s3, amazon

I work with channel images and my remote location is amazon S3. as our content theam is creating galleries on live site, I would like to create these galleries also on development. is there any simple solution to create a gallery with images already uploaded on S3?

otherwise I have to upload images on development again and a new gallery is created in my remote, which is not needed.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the issue, but can you not simply point your dev at the existing S3 bucket?

Comment: you understood wrong. I could solved it with just import database from live to dev, so I had the same gallery on dev. but my original question was, if there is any function instead of uploading images with channel manager. I mean something like just set a folder from S3 and channel images will use the same folder for the gallery, instead of creating a new folder with a new id.